# arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis giving ERROR 000210?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, error-000210

I have two polygon feature classes (buildings), one with attributes in green in the example below (building_sample.shp) and one with no attributes in red in the same example (building_sample_NA.shp).

[image]

I want the red buildings to take the attribute values of their closest green neighbor using arcpy.

Following the description of the SpatialJoin_analysis function, that should be easy but my code is not working:

> ERROR 000210: Cannot create output

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/DemoData/outputs"
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis (target_features = "building_sample_NA.shp",
                      join_features = "building_sample.shp",
                      out_feature_class = "building_completed",
                      join_operation = "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE",
                      match_option = "CLOSEST")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error appears to be that you have made a mistake in capitalization.

Where you have:

```
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True
```

it should be:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```